# Show InfoWindow of point on map long press

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Using the Google Maps app as an example for what I mean, when you long press on the map it loads the closest address in an InfoWindow.

How can I display an `InfoWindow` on the position of the map that I just long pressed on without putting down a marker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that Google Maps app adds a marker with 1x1px transparent bitmap (or maybe even 0x0px).

Comment: that is what I did I was just hoping there was a way I didnt have to add another marker to the map

Answer (score 0):

> To detect onMapLongClick:
>
> 1. Implement OnMapLongClickListener
> 2. Call myMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this) to register.
> 3. Override onMapLongClick(LatLng point) to add marker by calling
>      myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title("title")).

```
@Override
 public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
  tvLocInfo.setText("New marker added@" + point.toString());
  myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(point.toString()));
 }
```

Here is an example for that. Check [here](http://android-er.blogspot.gr/2013/01/google-maps-android-api-v2-example_3.html)
When you've created the marker it's easy to add an infowindow to that marker and open it.